# Not aligning horizon and vertically image inside parent

Tags: css

I want to position an image object in the middle of his parent. But this doesn't work for me. I have tried it with `display:table;` etc.

My JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wFg9a/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `display: table-cell;` on parent and use this on the image:

```
figcaption img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFg9a/8/)

Comment: I was about to post the same.

Comment: Keep in mind caveats of this.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is breaking the table cell behaviour.

Also vertical position should be middle not center.

Added a centered div to fix:

```
.post-entry .centered {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wFg9a/11/